# Tables not changing when navigating to new route

Tags: node.js, meteor, datatables, iron-router, spacebars

Here's my route.js (using the latest version of Iron Router and Tabular - https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-tabular);

```
Router.route('/orders', {
  name: 'orders',
  data: {
    datatable: TabularTables.Orders
  }
});

Router.route('/venues', {
  name: 'venues',
  data: {
    datatable: TabularTables.Venues
  }
});
```

Template HTML:

```
<template name="main">
    <h1>Header</h1>
    {{> tabular table=datatable class="ui table"}}
    <h3>Footer</h3>
</template>
```

Problem is when changing routes (i.e. navigating from "orders" to "venues" or vice versa, the datable won't reload and shows blank on the subsequent route. Is there a way to force-reload the table when switching routes?

Note that manually refreshing the page in the browser fixes the issue.

Comment: Try wrapping your `data:` stuffs in a function. `data: function(){ return { datatable: TabularTables.Venues }; }` like dis

Comment: Tried the above code, still no luck...the datatable does not want to even render. Opened an issue on the official Tabular GitHub page: https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-tabular/issues/94